# how can a database be created on sql server 2005 using c# vs08

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

to create new a new databse file start sql server management studio express on db server and create it!

i would like to create a database using c# in my web application visual studio 08

is it possible?

as connection string has to have a name of database to connect, but i want to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect master database and then create another db.
[Microsoft says like that.](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q307283&ID=KB;EN-US;Q307283&LN=EN-US&rnk=1&SD=msdn&FR=0&qry=Q307283&src=DHCS_MSPSS_msdn_SRCH&SPR=MSALL&)